# IOS application support which kind of virtual server?

Tags: iphone, ios

currently I am trying to create a routing service on the server side which will then send the result to the application. may i know which virtual server does the iOS application supported and can someone provide some basic knowledge about setting up the virtual server?

Comment: Please rephrase your issue, especially what is "routing service" and what you mean by "virtual server".

Comment: routing service here i mean to be the road routing service. and i want make the routing process just process on the server side nor the client side to save the resource of client device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't care what is running on the server side. It can connect to any standard TCP or UDP server. Of course it is a bit easier to use an existing protocol like HTTP, but ultimately that doesn't matter. 3rd party libraries like CocoaAsyncSocket and ASIHTTPRequest can make things easier on the iOS side. It's hard to offer any advice about what to do on the server side without any information as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: routing service that i mean is the road routing service. The thing i want to accomplish is get the user origin and destination then send it over the virtual server and the virtual server will calculate the route for the user and send it back the result and display to the user. hope u guys clear what i am trying to express.

Comment: What are you describing is a pretty standard web service. You could just use an HTTP server with some CGI scripts. There are thousands of tutorials for this online.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification, take a look at the [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) which can easily be accessed from the iPhone. It's a RESTful webservice that supports both JSON and XML as response format. You can check out [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) example on JSON over HTTP for more detailed info.

Comment: So if my virtual server develop using JAVA EE, it should can be connect to the server to make request and get the message. right?